# Visual Studio 2010 hangs when starting asp.net site debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

i have problem with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 x64. When i started asp.net site debugging, it stoped working. Only solution is restarting IIS.
Have anyone experiences with this?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use processExporer to see what part is stop working. I have a similar experience with the help module, that stop for some reason, and everything stop down.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. For me debugging works the first time after the project loads and hangs with any subsequent debugging attempts. There's an issue for this in Microsoft Connect.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556000/

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Only thing I can find is this in my worker process log:
DEBUG /DebugAttach.aspx - 443 - 127.0.0.1 - 401 0 0 0

And this in the EventViewer:
The remote debugger is unable to communicate with Visual Studio, and must abort the remote debugging session. Please restart debugging.

Answer (score 3):

As Peter mentioned, manually attaching through the Attach to Process dialog should work.

Another option is to temporarily update your project to .NET Framework v4.0. In the IDE, this can be done in 'Build' section of under project properties.

We are still investigating the issue to find a longer term solution.

Sorry for the inconvenience that this problem has caused.

Answer (score 1):

This M$ Connect article points straight to the topic: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556000/vs-2010-hangs-when-debugging-asp-net-3-5-web-application-or-website

Apart from the different intermediate solutions proposed, there seems to be an *official* Microsoft VS 2010 HotFix available here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2106584/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4834.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that helped me:

Go to Debug->Attach to Process. If the 'Attach To' box says 'Automatic: Native code' then click the 'Select...' button. In the 'Select Code Type' dialog change the option from 'Automatically determine the type of code to debug' to 'Debug these code types' and choose ONLY the options for you project. For me this was 'Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0)'. Click OK. Then click Cancel in the 'Attach to Process' dialog.

At this point I'm now able to do F5 Debugging.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

For what it is worth I had this problem this morning out of nowhere. In my case I am converting a database into webpages and one of the folders of one of the projects in my solution now has over 200 thousand html web pages. As soon as I one off'd my solution and removed the project with the giant folder debugging worked again.

This is not unlike what happens when performing a global search and vs 2010 tries to search a folder with an enormous # of files.