# Visual Studio 2010 iis express freezes when debugging multiple websites

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution in which I'm debugging two websites simultaneously. Not long after the debug is started and something throws an error, Visual Studio will freeze and I get the tray icon and message 'Visual studio is busy. Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting for an internal operation to complete. If you regularly encounter this delay during normal usage, please report this problem to Microsoft.'  Sometimes I can Exit the iis express process through the tray icon and get Visual Studio to respond but sometimes I have to kill the iisexpress task.

I've attached the debugger from a different instance to the problem instance before the freeze and found nothing useful.

I attached two separate debugger instances to the two iisexpress processes and when I start to debug the site, the debuggers become automatically unattached to the iisexpress processes.

I found this article but the links seem to address asp.net 3.5 and mine are 4.0 projects.

[Visual Studio 2010 hangs when starting asp.net site debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764186/visual-studio-2010-hangs-when-starting-asp-net-site-debugging)

Is anyone else experiencing this and know a fix?

Comment: Do you have IIS installed? if so, i recommend to use it. I was also in similar vain. IIS express is a striped down version of IIS and lacking features. If you want to run mutiple web apps, you can configure those in to different ports of IIS.

Comment: Actually where I work we're forced to use IIS Express for the time being. Unless it becomes something that can't possibly be resolved then maybe IIS could be a possibility.  I don't know if this is normal, but it seems that maybe devenv is leaking memory. When devenv locks up totally and I have to use task manager to kill it, the memory usage is around 500MB.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a very similar situation.
I downloaded IIS 7.5 Express installer and did a repair. After that problem disappeared.

I used [this IIS 7.5 installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038) from Download Center.