# Visual Studio 2010 hangs on attach to process / debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, freeze

Whenever I try to debug a Visual Studio 2010 web project, VS hangs, and ultimately crashes. This happens if I try to start the project using F5, or through Attach to Process, *before* the process list even appears.

Hitting F5 in, for example, a Windows Form project works fine, but attach to process fails here too.

Any ideas on what can be causing this? Obviously attaching to the devenv.exe process won't work as I can't get the Attach to Process dialog to appear...

Oh, running W7 (x64), VS2010 SP1 (had same problems without SP1)

Comment: What version of .NET does the project target? There is an issue with a hotfix for 3.5 projects in VS2010: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5148832/7376

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 (devenv) Hung Process After Closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204835/visual-studio-2010-devenv-hung-process-after-closing)

Comment: Duplicate suggest standard set of steps dealing with such issue (even if it is for slightly different case).

Comment: Same issue here, but mine doesn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

In **Solution Explorer** there is a **Show All Files** icon (highlighted in the photo below):

Make sure it's turned off,
When It's turned on, Visual Studio tries to index all the files in the solution and if you have a giant Solution it could take forever!

[image]

I hope this has helped someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently installed Mono and/or Mono Tools for VS2010?
I found that to be the problem it my case. Not sure why, but it somehow got in the way.

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

In my case hangs when executable type was not correctly set, ex. Managed v4.0 and trying to attach to Native.